# What's the point on property taxes?

Tags: taxes

Why is it that in some western jurisdictions there's a notion of property tax?

If a owner buys a property, why do they need to pay further and periodically for it, since it is namely theirs?

I can understand that it can be confiscated from the owner for debt purposes, but not for not paying taxes for it.

It seems from my point of view that these property taxes are just a guise of having these properties actually rented to their actual buyers by the state (or government), so this notion seems baseless in my little and insignificant unqualified opinion.

Comment: Related: https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/42027/20220

Comment: "If a owner buys a property, why do they need to pay further and periodically for it, since it is namely theirs?" -- There's your first mistake: assuming life is fair and rational.

Comment: Rather, your first mistake is assuming that if you buy a property, it is yours.

Comment: @user253751 Well owning's the purpose and that's what it's supposed to be.

Comment: @abdul "Ownership" is more complicated than the word makes it appear.

Comment: @user253751 As far as common sense is concerned, ownership means to have a good at disposal under property, so...

Comment: @user253751, so it might be one of the [several and numerous] flaws that the western system has and tries to hide with the guise of civilisation and "quality" of life compared to poorer areas of the world and then blackmail morally people by telling them that they're lucky to live in the west and so forth. I do know that the west has its own propaganda and mind control system, I'm not that naive.

Comment: @abdul Common sense does not say that there are no "catches" to ownership. And flaws should be measured in terms of outcomes, not methods.

Comment: @use25371 not really. Moreover in this case the outcome is that a owner is forced to pay for owing a thing.